# grep --quiet in square brackets

Tags: bash, grep, conditional-statements

knows someone the why of this behavior using grep -q please?
I have a file which contains the word "pippo".

```
1)
if [[ $(cat file | grep pippo) ]]; then echo OK; else echo KO; fi
--> OK
2)
if cat file | grep -q pippo; then echo OK; else echo KO; fi
--> OK    
3)
if [[ $(cat file | grep -q pippo) ]]; then echo OK; else echo KO; fi
--> KO
```

The "-q" option for grep: does not write anything to standard output.  Exit immediately with zero status if any  match  is  found,  even  if  an  error  was detected.
Why 3rd returns OK? 
Thank you

Comment: But it returns "KO". `$(cat file | grep -q pippo)` expands to the empty string, and `[[ '' ]]` is a short form of `[[ -n '' ]]` and is false.

Comment: Why are you using `cat file | grep pippo` instead of `grep pippo file`?

Comment: it's the same and it doesn't affect on the example.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a zero length string.

```
$ a=$(cat file | grep -q "pippo")
$ echo $a

$ if [[ $a ]]; then echo ok; else echo err; fi
err
```

`grep -q` is normally used to get the exit code of `grep` command, not to compare a string. Recommended use would be,

```
$ if grep -q "pippo" file; then echo ok; else err; fi
```

Above will do a truth evaluation of `grep -q "pippo" file`.

Answer (score 0):

the reason is this:

```
if [[ '' ]]; then echo OK; else echo KO; fi
--> KO
```

the second works as intended since that's what this `if` is doing, without the `[[...]]` it's saying 'if this command succeeds' or 'if this command doesn't exit with an error'

so the `[[` operator will be evaluating the output of your `$(...)`, not it's return value. You may check with

```
if [[ $(echo boo) == boo ]]; then echo ok; fi
--> ok
```

but your `grep -q` isn't outputting anything that may be evaluated.

you may read `man bash`, particularly the sections `Compound commands` which will explain the `[[` operator and `CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS` which will explain what is evaluated inside the `[[`.